# How to specify positions that will be replaced with Regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have regular expression `(?!\,)(?!X){3}[0-9\.\w\s\+\-\:\,]+` and strings like

```
"1", "S1", "S2", "1", "2"
"1", "S1", "S2", "1", 2
"1", "S1", "S2", "1", "2", 3
```

I am trying to parse that string with Regex (by matches) and I am not strong in regular expressions.

I need to process elements `"1", "S1", "S2"` and to skip elements `"1", "2"`. The first idea is to specify in regular expression logic like "don't take occururences, that are first from right ("2"-2) and second from right ("1"-1), but take all other occurences".

The main idea is that this logic should be made with only regular expression, not by C# code (I am talking about Match object position in C# matches array - no C# logic, regular expression should be used only).

How can I change my regular expression `(?!\,)(?!X){3}[0-9\.\w\s\+\-\:\,]+` to specify positions, that are should not be processed?

Comment: What do you try to match with the regex? It does not match anything sensible: the `(?!X){3}` lookahead is quantified, the lookaheads are unanchored, the character class contains `0-9` while `\w` is already there...

Comment: This should be parsed with a CSV parser. A regex solution will be fraught with errors. Something like `(?<=^"|,\s*")[^"]+(?="$|",)(?!(?:",\s*"[^"]*){0,1}"$)` does what you need.

Comment: So you want everything on the left leading up to the last two elements?

Comment: To MonkeyZeus: Yep, you are right. I need to ignore last two occurences.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
^.*(?= *, *"?.*?"?, *"?.*?"?)
```

This will match everything leading up to the last two elements.

https://regex101.com/r/wMWaKF/2

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I've updated my question because looks like I asked it in wrong form. Input strings could be `"1", "S1", "S2", "1", "2"`, 
`"1", "S1", "S2", "1", 2`, 
`"1", "S1", "S2", "1", "2", 3` So, this reg exp will work not for all of my input strings. I mean, strings are dynamically sized by length

Comment: @Arthur A small modification is needed to accommodate quote-less values such as integers. See my updated regex and regex101 link.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting solution, but it brakes logic "select each element" `(?!\,)(?!X){3}[0-9\.\w\s\+\-\:\,]+`. Ie, matches look like whole part `"1", "S1", "S2"`, not splitted by elements. In my reg exp each match is each element - https://regex101.com/r/eU18aV/1 . Is it possible to merge your reg exp with mine, to get matches of each element of line, except last two elements?

Comment: @Arthur You can try something like `"?(.*?)"?(?= *, *"?.*?"?, *"?.*?"?)` but you should really just use a CSV parser.